# How to manipulate an Access database with SQL and C# in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I'm basically trying to run SQL commands on an already connected Access database and show the results, I've already built some SQL queries in the design view of the dataset but I am unable to view them on the main forms' datagrid, using C# in VS 2010.

How do I execute the SQL commands on a connected Access database and view them in the datagrid on the main form?

Please Help

Comment: Please add some code to check

Comment: I have no code yet, I've only connected the database to the application by means of the wizard and created a few queries in the design view. The database name is Customer_details and the table contained is named Details

Comment: Your question isn't really obvious - can you please reword your question into the form of a question? At this point there is nothing to answer because you haven't asked anything.

Comment: I reworded your indirect question as a direct question. Please check that I have properly captured your intent.